# Getting key from table not known at compile time

Tags: hashmap, nim-lang

I'm trying to get a value from a table without knowing if it contains a given key at compile time.

```
proc getFirst(table: Table[int, string]): string =
  return table[0]

var t = initTable[int, string]()
t.add(0, "I like turtles")

echo t[0]                        # works!
echo t.getFirst()                # works!    

echo t[1]                        # Error: unhandled exception: key not found: 1 [KeyError]

const str: string = t.getFirst() # Error: cannot evaluate at compile time: t
echo str
```

`echo t[0]` and `echo t[1]` work exactly as I expected.

`echo t.getFirst()` confuses me a bit. I guess the compiler is able to infer that the key exists. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

`const str: string = t.getFirst()` does not work at all. Even by editing the proc to check if the key exists first, like

```
proc getFirst(table: Table[int, string]): string =
  if table.hasKey(0):
    return table[0]
  else:
    return "I do not exist!"
```

will produce the same compiler error. Is there a way to get a table's key this way?

Comment: You're trying to assign a value from a runtime variable to a compile-time constant. It's not supposed to work this way. Could you explain what exactly do you want to archieve?

Comment: Oh lord, I totally forgot about `let`. That was the problem. Still stuck in the Java mindset. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the index table[0] if the table is empty will generate an exception ("key not found"). I think you need something like this:

```
import json,tables

proc get(table: Table[int, string]; index : int): string =
  if table.len() <= 0:
    result = "empty"
  else:
    if table.hasKey(index):
      return table[index]
    else:
      return "missing"

var t = initTable[int, string]()
t.add(0, "I like turtles")

echo t[0]      # works butgenerates exception if table is empty!
echo t.get(0)  # works even if table is empty or table[0] is missing

echo t.get(2)  # missing

for key,value in t.pairs():
  echo $key & " " & value
```

**Output**

I like turtles

I like turtles

missing

0 I like turtles